# Handle session time out with Wicket

Tags: wicket

I'm working on a wicket legacy-project and i'm trying to fix a bug with the session time-out. 
Basically I'd like to have a redirect to a customed error page after session times out. 
This is what I did:

web.xml :

```xml
  <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

in the application class:

```java
@Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(ErrorMessagePage.class);
```

This is not working. I mean after session time out, nothing happens. 
What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT 04.05.20

Based on the feedback from Martin I tried to implement a session validaty checker:

```java
public class SessionValidityChecker implements IRequestCycleListener {

@Override
    public void onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) cycle.getRequest().getContainerRequest();

        boolean sessionValid = request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();
        if (!sessionValid) {
            cycle.setResponsePage(SessionExpiredPage.class);
        }
    }
}
```

and in Application.class

```java
 public void init() {
        super.init();
        getRequestCycleListeners().add(new SessionValidityChecker());
}
```

Also what I may should have specified in my first post is that I use the wicket SignInPanel for authentification. After timeout, I'd like the user to be logged out and redirected to a specific page.

This is what I've tried with the above code, but after session time out, no redirect happens. Even worst, the user is still signed in. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaking page expiration with session expiration.
Stateful pages are stored in a PageStore (disk) and the store may grow up to some predefined size. Once this size is reached the oldest page is removed to make room for the newest one.
If your user uses the browser Back button many times at some point Wicket will throw PageExpiredException for the deleted page.

In your case when the session expires usually the web server (e.g. Tomcat) will just create a new one. If your application has authentication enabled then it will detect that there is no authenticated user in the new http session and most probably will redirect the user to the login page.

If there is no authentication in place then Wicket will create a new instance of the requested page and render it. You can change this by changing `PageSettings#recreateBookmarkablePagesAfterExpiry` to `false`
(see https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/79f63f66eb588a5d69e9feff7066f1244f61f387/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/settings/PageSettings.java#L46)

You may use javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isRequestedSessionIdValid() method to find whether the the request came with an expired JSESSIONID cookie/url. If it is false then the web server just created a new HttpSession. You can do the check in Wicket's IRequestCycleListener#onBeginRequest()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if, after session time out, i want the user to be redirected not to the login page, but let's say a custom Expired page. Which method should I use? How to have the control over this?

Comment: You may use javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isRequestedSessionIdValid() method to find whether the the request came with an expired JSESSIONID cookie/url. If it is `false` then the web server just created a new HttpSession. You can do the check in Wicket's IRequestCycleListener#onBeginRequest()

Comment: Hi Martin, could you by chance have a look on my edit?